# Avoid handling own action on shared observable collection's event

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection which is shared between two client classes.
Each of them can change the collection. When it occurs, the other class should do some 
handling action.
How can each client class avoid handling its own action?

Comment: A *flag* should be pretty easy to use to solve that. Set `bool` before changing collection, reset after. When other class receive event if first checks flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything in the `CollectionChanged` event that could help you. The `sender` is just the collection itself, and the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` doesn't have any info you could use for this purpose either.

I suppose what you could do is subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event initially in each class, so they're ready to listen if something's added. But then when you try to add an item from one class or the other, have them unsubscribe from the event first, add or remove the item, then re-subscribe to it.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    ObservableCollection<int> myObservableColl = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    public SomeClass()
    {
        myObservableColl.CollectionChanged += MainWindowViewModel_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void AddItem(int number)
    {
        myObservableColl.CollectionChanged -= MainWindowViewModel_CollectionChanged;
        myObservableColl.Add(number);
        myObservableColl.CollectionChanged += MainWindowViewModel_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        myObservableColl.CollectionChanged -= MainWindowViewModel_CollectionChanged;
        myObservableColl.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);
        myObservableColl.CollectionChanged += MainWindowViewModel_CollectionChanged;
    }

    // etc, etc.
}
```

If you didn't want to make a whole bunch of methods, you could define one like this:

```
private void ChangeCollectionWithoutNotification(Action action)
{
    myObservableColl.CollectionChanged -= MainWindowViewModel_CollectionChanged;
    action.Invoke();
    myObservableColl.CollectionChanged += MainWindowViewModel_CollectionChanged;
}
```

And then pass an action to it:

```
ChangeCollectionWithoutNotification(() => myObservableColl.Add(5));

ChangeCollectionWithoutNotification(() => myObservableColl.Move(1, 2));
```

Comment: Thank you, Grant. I think I'll use it